# Whats the best way to refactor a POCO class

Tags: c#, .net

In work I was asked to fix a bug which involved me making changes in a class. To fix the bug I needed to add a collection of a class that looks like this.

```
public class Branch
{
    public int StartNode { get; set; }
    
    public int EndNode { get; set; }
}
```

The collection

```
List<Branch> _vistedBranch = new List<Branch>();
```

My concern is I was always taught to hate seeing "new" in any of my classes as it tightly couples my class to other classes. However this class is just a POCO class that doesn't have any functionality. I am just using it in the class I am working on to store a collection of start nodes and end nodes.

This is how I have used it in the class

```
public class CustomerCountRequestProcessor : ICustomerCountRequestProcessor
{
    List<Branch> _vistedBranch = new List<Branch>();
    private INetwork _network;
    public CustomerCountRequestProcessor(INetwork network)
    {
        _network = network ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(network));
    }

    public int GetCustomersForSelectedNode(IRoot request)
    {
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));

        _network = request.Network;
        return ProcessSelectedNode(request.SelectedNode);
    }

    private int ProcessSelectedNode(int node)
    {
        var nc = _network.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Node == node);
        var customersForNode = nc != null ? nc.NumberOfCustomers : 0;

        foreach (var subNode in _network.Branches.Where(b => b.StartNode == node))
        {
            bool has = _vistedBranch.Any(b => b.StartNode == subNode.StartNode
                && b.EndNode == subNode.EndNode);
            if (has)
            { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); }
            _vistedBranch.Add(new Branch()
            {
                StartNode = subNode.StartNode,
                EndNode = subNode.EndNode
            });
            customersForNode += ProcessSelectedNode(subNode.EndNode);
        }

        return customersForNode;
    }
}
```

1.Do I make a class out of the collection. Then make an interface out of the class then bring it in using dependency injection?

2.Do I make a factory class, stick that collection in there and then new up the factory when I need the class? These options above seem a lot of code for one simple POCO class. Maybe its just as simple as putting the new part into the constructor like this.

```
List<Branch> _vistedBranch;
private INetwork _network;
public CustomerCountRequestProcessor(INetwork network)
{
    _vistedBranch = new List<Branch>();
    _network = network ??
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(network));
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I think that KISS applies in this scenario. `_visitedBranch` is not a public-facing property, and is used in one place purely for validation. Writing more code to try and hide the `new` keyword in this instance is counter-productive, especially since it's a simple POCO. I'd go as far to say that if `Branch` is only ever used in that class, make it a Tuple to remove the need for that class entirely.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @user16405900 Why do want to have Dependency Injection or Factory method? What would be your gain then? What is your main concern that you want to address with these techniques?

Comment: My main concern is stated in the question, whats the best way to refactor a POCO class. I discuss Dependency Injection and Factory's because I am newing up classes in another class and when you do that they come into the conversation. So if you understand why people use DI and factories then you understand what the gain is. I guess if I want to extend the the functionality of my POCO class or Test and Moq the POCO class then I would need DI or Factory.  But as this POCO class will never be used in anyother way than to collect data in this class then I can just leave as is.

Comment: @user16405900 *what's the best way to refactor a POCO class* Refactoring is not a concern, it is a tool. Testability might be a concern, Independent deployability, reuse or responsibility segregation might be a concern. DI and Factory methods are common solutions to address the above problems. Maybe if I rephrase my question it might help: What is the problem with your current solution that you want to address?

Comment: Ok to be clear. My concern as a relatively new developer is I am told to hate seeing the keyword new in classes. So I guess I am asking you should I be concerned with what I have done. Or am I maintaining clean coding principles. So when you look at that Code is it clean and how you would have done it?

Comment: @user16405900 `new` should be avoided if you are dealing with dependencies. `ClassA` should not be responsible for `ClassB`'s life-cycle. The best way to avoid to is to delegate this to a separate component, like DI. In your case `_visitedBranch` is not a dependency, it is an implementation detail from your class's consumer point of view. So, it is not a problem to use here `new`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Makes sense

Answer (score 1):

> Do I make a class out of the collection

You did - `List<Branch>`, but it is not being used. Everywhere `_vistedBranch` (spelling?) is iterated something like `_vistedBranch.Find(<expression>)`,  `Contains(item)`,  etc. could be used.

MS recommends NOT inheriting `List<T>:` but encapsulation is better anyway:

```
public class Branches {
   public List<Branch> _branches  { get;  protected set;  }
   
   public Branches  {   _branches = new List<Branch>();  }
   
   public bool Add ( Branch newBranch ) {
      if ( newBranch == null ) return false;
      if  ( _branches.Contains( newBranch ) return false;
      _branches.Add( newBranch );
     return true;
   }
```

The collection itself  controls what is allowed or not. Keeps the coder (`Branch`'s client code)  from screwing up  or screwing around with the extensive `List` functionality.

---

> Do I make a factory class

No. A properly implemented `Branches` class is inherently reusable and flexible.

---

> Then make an interface out of the class

No. How many differently-functioning `List<Branches>` are needed. Or, more to the purpose of `interface`, what non-`List<Branch>` objects  need that functionality? I suspect that `List` methods (see above) with their parameterized (injectable) expressions makes an `interface` moot.

---

> bring it in using dependency injection

Yes. But all the collection functionality has to be taken oout of `CustomerCountRequestProcessor` first.

---

**Implement `IEquatable` and `IComparable` in `Branch` ?**

This code makes me wonder:

```
Any(b => b.StartNode == subNode.StartNode
            && b.EndNode == subNode.EndNode)
```

That is easily replaced by `_vistedBranch.Contains(otherBranch)` for example **if `Branch` had identity equality**.

> hate seeing "new" in any of my classes as it tightly couples my class to other classes.

`CustomerCountRequestProcessor` is the collection for all practical purposes. The coupling is not in `new` but the collection functionaly usurped by `CustomerCountRequestProcessor`.  Instantiating the internal reference makes a lot of sense if an empty collection is a valid use case or valid initial state.

`Branches.Add()` (above) works the very first time because the internal collection is empty, not null. Thus  empty & not-empty collections are treated the same without  special `null` handling code.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I feel my question hasnt been answered or maybe I dont understand. As now I am back to square one. If I implement your Branches class into my CustomerCountRequestProcessor, I have to use the new keyword like this new Branches();. Should I do that or should I bring it in using dependency injection and in order to do dependency injection I will need to make the Branches class an Interface?

Comment: That "no new" heuristic is nonsense. Any other-class reference is coupling, that's how software works. Passing in a collection is coupling. Extreme decoupling is one "god" class - the opposite of good software structure, OO or not. **It is a design issue of composition vs aggregation**: [here](https://medium.com/swlh/aggregation-vs-composition-in-object-oriented-programming-3fa4fd471a9f)  ...  [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/61376/38663)   and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/200487/38663)

Comment: `new` up a collection in `CustomerCountRequestProcessor` if you want aggregation, pass in a collection if you want composition. That is independent of `Branches` implementation/functionality. Using internal collection object reference will be exactly the same either way.  If `CCRP` will ever have only one collection and might want to control access and contents then use aggregation. The collection must be instantiated *somewhere*, if not this class then some other class.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Makes sense